# QFileSystem entryInfo not returning full directories name

Tags: c++, qt, filesystems

So i have some duplicate songs in my Itunes library (844 to be precise) so i thought I would write a small program to find and destroy the duplicates. The problem I have encountered is some of the directories are not being read correctly.

For example one of album's folder name is "Greatest Hits, Vol. 2" But is read "Greatest Hits, Vol"

Obviously the "." is causing a problem. Does anyone know of a workaround that will allow me to read the full file path name (with periods)?

small snipit of Code

```
QString name;
int id;
    for (int a = 0; a < dir.entryList(QDir::Files | QDir::AllDirs | QDir::NoDotAndDotDot).length(); ++a)
        {
            name =  path() + "/" + baseName() + "/" + dir.entryList(QDir::AllEntries | QDir::NoDotAndDotDot).at(a);
            subFiles.append(new CKClone(id, path() + "/" + baseName() + "/" + dir.entryList(QDir::AllEntries | QDir::NoDotAndDotDot).at(a), this));

            // Updating the ID number to account for descendants.
            id = subFiles.last()->countDescendants(id);
        }
```

The above code is just a small snipit and obviously doesn't do a whole bunch on its own. It simply reads in all of the files and directories recursively.

Any help will be appreciated, Thanks

Jec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually tested this in PyQt and found that the problem does not occur for me. This is tested using Qt 4.8, so you may want to check if its a problem specific to your version.

Dir structure like this:

```
testing/
    a path with spaces/
    patH_with_no_spaces/
    path with version, vol. 2/
```

Test snippet

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore

d = QtCore.QDir("testing")
list(d.entryList(d.AllEntries|d.NoDotAndDotDot))

# output
[
    PyQt4.QtCore.QString(u'a path with spaces'), 
    PyQt4.QtCore.QString(u'path with version, vol. 2'), 
    PyQt4.QtCore.QString(u'patH_with_no_spaces')
]
```

You might want to first try simplifying your code a bit more to see if its a bug in your code. You seem to be regenerating your list every time you loop, build a string, and append. Try saving the QStringList result of that `entryList` call once before your loop, and using that same object for the rest of the code.

Comment: You were right, I was polling for the entries multiple times. Thats what happens when I code late at night :)  Thanks a lot